# How do I use M3 dynamic colors in my app's launcher icon?

Tags: android, material-components, material3, material-you

I want to use M3 colors like `?attr/colorPrimary` in my app's launcher icon. I know this is possible because my phone's Settings app does it. I've looked around quite a bit and couldn't find anything related to this.

[image]
[image]

I've tried setting my foreground icon color `<path android:fillColor="?attr/colorPrimary" ... />`, but this just gave a blank icon.

I even tried setting a tint to the adaptive icon `<foreground android:tint="?attr/colorPrimary" ... />`, but this didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings.git/+/refs/heads/android12-release/res/values/colors.xml#143) of Android 12's Settings app, it looks like they're using the following private property as the launcher icon's background color.

```xml
<color name="icon_launcher_setting_color">@*android:color/accent_device_default_light</color>
```

This probably works for Android 12 Pixel devices as it's normally not recommended to use private properties because there's a chance they won't exist in the system. In other words, this isn't a good solution.

---

This is the solution I finally went with which worked nicely for me.

**values/colors.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="launcher_icon_background_color">@color/m3_sys_color_light_primary</color>
</resources>
```

**values/colors.xml (v31)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="launcher_icon_background_color">@android:color/system_accent1_600</color>
</resources>
```

And finally I used `@color/launcher_icon_background_color` in my foreground icon's `fillColor`.